# Why doesn't my code work when I try to access global variables in my PHP function?

Tags: php, database

I have

```
require_once 'db_connect.php'
```

inside which is

```
$db_name = ...
```

Then directly below I have

```
function my_func() {
global $db_name; 
}
```

However `$db_name` is returning a blank value.  What am I doing wrong?

Update: If I print $db_name directly after require_once it works fine.  However all this is part of a sidebar in wordpress therefore I'm not sure about function scope.

Comment: `global $variable;` is the answer to the question from the title. You have to rephrase it, "How can I find, why my code doesn't work"

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top and check for **typos**

Comment: also, because it's code problem, posting here a **real** code can dramatically improve your chances to get an answer.

Comment: place require 'db_connect.php' inside your function and check if the var is filled.

Comment: Off topic, but as a suggestion you might want to use a [define](http://www.php.net/define) for such low level configuration information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** My answer was tailored to the original version of the question. Please note that the answer below was an answer based on information available at the time.

When you `require()` or `include()` the included script runs in the same scope than the line where the file is being included.

Consider the following:

**myscript.php**

```
<?php
function init_db() {
  require_once("database.inc.php");
}

echo $db_name;

function test() {
  global $db_name;
  echo $db_name;
}

test();
```

**database.inc.php**

```
<?php
$db_name = "hello";
```

Since **database.inc.php** is being included in the function `init_db()`, none of the `echo` will actually output anything. `$db_name` is local to the function `init_db()`.

To remedy that, simply add `global $db_name;` to the **database.inc.php** file:

**database.inc.php**

```
<?php
global $db_name;
$db_name = "hello";
```

Think of `require()` or `include()` as copy-pasting code where it is called. Since you are inside the function `init_db()` when **database.inc.php** is executed, `global $db_name;` will allow you to set `$db_name` globally.

Answer (score 0):

The two things that spring to mind are, is $db_name actually being assigned the value you expect it to be getting, and are you including the file in the global scope?

If $db_name is being assigned a value by a function that might fail (for example mysql_connect will only return a connection handle if a connection with the database is established) then $db_name might be being assigned a NULL value.

Included files inherit the scope from which the include statement was executed.  If you include inside a function, then any values assigned in the include will only be in that function's scope and will cease to exist outside of scope.  Ditto for classes and methods.  Please make sure your include statement is being executed in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use `global` keyword to bring variables into the scope, I would recommend using superglobal `$GLOBALS` array. (Explicit is better than implicit). And I mean not only in your function that *uses* a global variable, but also in a file that *defines* it.

```
// db_connect.php
$GLOBALS['db_name'] = 'my_db_name';
```

This way, when someone (even you, a month later) is looking at your `db_connect.php` he will instantly understand that this variable is supposed to be in global scope, and will think twice before trying to rename it.